# error installing cuda 9.1 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, 18.04

Error I have is :

```
kapil@firefly:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install cuda-9-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-9-1 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: cuda-runtime-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: cuda-demo-suite-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-384 : Depends: nvidia-headless-390 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-387-dev : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-390 : Depends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

kapil@firefly:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install cuda-toolkit-9-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-toolkit-9-1 : Depends: cuda-compiler-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-tools-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-samples-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-documentation-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-libraries-dev-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-license-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-384 : Depends: nvidia-headless-390 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-387-dev : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-390 : Depends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

kapil@firefly:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install cuda-demo-suite-9-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-demo-suite-9-1 : Depends: cuda-runtime-9-1 but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-384 : Depends: nvidia-headless-390 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-387-dev : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-390 : Depends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

kapil@firefly:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install cuda-runtime-9-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-runtime-9-1 : Depends: cuda-libraries-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: cuda-license-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-384 : Depends: nvidia-headless-390 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-387-dev : Depends: nvidia-387 (>= 387.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-390 : Depends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

kapil@firefly:~/Downloads$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbsd0:i386 libffi6:i386 libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-387 nvidia-387 nvidia-opencl-icd-387 ocl-icd-libopencl1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-384 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386
  nvidia-390 nvidia-libopencl1-304
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-387 nvidia-387 nvidia-opencl-icd-387 ocl-icd-libopencl1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/84.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 193 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  nvidia-387 387.26-0ubuntu1 [77.7 MB]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  libcuda1-387 387.26-0ubuntu1 [3,395 kB]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  nvidia-opencl-icd-387 387.26-0ubuntu1 [3,529 kB]
(Reading database ... 152738 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-387_387.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-387 (387.26-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-9-1-local/./nvidia-387_387.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules', which is also in package nvidia-kernel-common-390 390.48-0ubuntu3+gpu18.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-9-1-local/./nvidia-387_387.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I had installed `nvidia-390` driver and now there is some clash for some reason. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `apt --fix-broken install` like the output suggests?

Comment: The last part of error contains output of this command.